# Want to create inner section of div using js

Tags: javascript

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3U7Gv.png)

I want to create the inner div again using js.

I have div of the class row in the container I want to add the new row section on click on the + button.

Comment: Please, post text as text, not as photographs of text. We want to copy&paste&run your code, copy&paste your inputs, read your outputs, and copy&paste&google your error messages, not critique your use of color and perspective. Also, please make sure to post everything relevant to answering your question *in your question*, not on some third-party site somewhere else. https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create an HTML div by using the JavaScript function:

```
let div = document.createElement('div')
```

You can then add properties to your div and append it to your container accordingly.

### Solution:

```
document.getElementById('buttonID').onclick = () => {
  let div = document.createElement('div');
  div.className = 'row';
  div.style.border = '1px solid darkgreen';
  div.style.padding = '20px';
  div.style.marginBottom = '10px';
  div.innerHTML = 'Abdullah';
  document.getElementById('main-container').appendChild(div);
}
```

** Although, I would recommend putting the style properties into the ***row*** CSS class. and then cutout the `div.style.*` lines of code above to get:

### Better Solution

**JS**

```
document.getElementById('buttonID').onclick = () => {
  let div = document.createElement('div');
  div.className = 'row';
  div.innerHTML = 'Abdullah';
  document.getElementById('main-container').appendChild(div);
}
```

**CSS**

```
row {
  border: 1px solid darkgreen;
  padding: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```